# How to integrate video in sharepoint 2013 and categorize by type - training,design

Tags: sharepoint, video, integrate

What is the best way to integrate  video in sharepoint  2013 and categorize by type - training,design. Could you help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go here is creating an Asset Library. See link below: 
[More information about Asset Library](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/set-up-an-asset-library-to-store-image-audio-or-video-files-HA102785730.aspx)

What you would also have to do is to add an additional column "categorytype" to your new Asset Library.Or you could create different Asset Libraries for different categories of course, depending on your specific needs.

Comment: Thank you so much Stefan.I have to create different Asset libraries for different categories.

Comment: Hi Stefan,I created different Asset libraries for different videos.I have to show all of the links in one page.If I click on those links it should redirect to corresponding videos.How to do that.Thanks in advance

Comment: The easiest way would by to display multiple listview-webparts, one for each Asset Library on a single page. on clikcing on an item you will get redirected to the corresponding item(video).

Comment: I got it .I did display the videos using listview webparts.Thank you so much Stefan

Comment: I have to integrate youtube videos and provide search functionality,provide thumbnails, have to adjust the video size,provide better look and feel  and categorize by type also.Is it better to develop custom webpart.